# Springboot application not reading custom ENVIRONMENT variables

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, environment-variables, redhat

I have recently started exploring JAVA and Springboot.
I came across a situation where I need to read an environment variable called e.g. "HERO"
Now, my following code, tries to read the same environment variable but fails!
For context, I am running RedHat8

```
SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Value("${HERO}")
    private String envVariable;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Value of HERO: " + envVariable);
    }
}
```

The ERROR

```
 Could not resolve placeholder 'HERO' in value "${HERO}"
```

I have double checked, the variable exists and is globally read able in terminals and is also added in BASHRC file.

Terminal:

```
main * $ echo $HERO
James Bond
```

.BASHRC file:

```
export HERO="James Bond"
```

However, it works when I try to read some other system environment variables.

For example, when I replace my varibale with `{HOME}`

then it does show `Value of HERO: /home/awesomemachine/clark`

What am I doing wrong? I have restarted, rebuilt and refreshed multiple times but unable to figure out! Any suggestions would be appreicated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is a good idea to use `@Value` in the `@SpringBootApplication` application class rather than in a `@Component` but anyway. You could fetch the environment variables via the application context like so:

```java
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApp.class).run(args);
Environment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
System.out.println(environment.getProperty("HERO"));
```

Answer (score 0):

with `@Value` annotation, you have to use `#systemEnvironment` notation to access system environment variables and assign them to a field, like this

```
package org.example;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Value("#{systemEnvironment['HERO']}")
    private String sysEnvField;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        log.info("SystemEnvironment: {}", sysEnvField);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

tested in IntelliJ idea w/ spring boot 3.1.8

[image]

That's console output:

```
2024-02-02T11:43:32.546+01:00  INFO 26968 --- [           main] org.example.MyApp                        : Starting MyApp using Java 17.0.6 with PID 26968 (C:\dev\workspace-intellij\stack-samples\spring-boot-system-environment\target\classes started by sriffaldi in C:\dev\workspace-intellij\stack-samples)
2024-02-02T11:43:32.548+01:00  INFO 26968 --- [           main] org.example.MyApp                        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-02-02T11:43:32.860+01:00  INFO 26968 --- [           main] org.example.MyApp                        : Started MyApp in 0.508 seconds (process running for 0.751)
2024-02-02T11:43:32.863+01:00  INFO 26968 --- [           main] org.example.MyApp                        : SystemEnvironment: foo

Process finished with exit code 0
```

as you can see, it's works even outside IDE (follow numbers)

[image]

Comment: I had tried something similar and got "null". Tried again and it's same
`SystemEnvironment: null`

Comment: java and spring-boot version ?

Comment: spring-boot 3.1.4 and java 17

Comment: I tried your exactly versions, it's works for me, even outside IDE (see edited answer). So, I'm pretty sure is something about variable visibility !

Comment: Have you tried to do the same but with @Value("${HERO}") ? :) @Stefano Riffaldi

Comment: no, I didn't. I try now, and it's work ! @Romario

Comment: Ta Da @Stefano Riffaldi  :)

Comment: @Romario I cant' downvote myself, but I deserve it. Do it :D

Comment: I won't @Stefano Riffaldi :)

Comment: is there a difference between `@Value("${HERO}")`and `@Value("#{systemEnvironment['HERO']}")` logically?